ZRLE decompression failed on wireshark
While sniffing in wireshark for VNC connection, I get an error message saying ZRLE decompression failed:
How can I enable decompression of ZRLE? I want to see the decompressed raw data.
I am running windows and have installed wireshrk and npcap of latest versions recently.
What is the cause of this issue ?


That doesn't say decompression was disabled; it says decompression failed. Is it actually valid ZRLE?

@grawity the thing is, my vncclient app works without issue, so the fail is with wireshark only then
